# Binding GridView after removing column

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-4.0

I am removing column from my GridView at one postback and binding it on second postback.
After binding when page gets rendered it does not displays my GridView.

The same code segment was working when i was using ASP.NET 3.5 but in 4.0 it does not display the GridView. Can anyone please tell me that why this situation is happening?

Thanks in advance.

.aspx Code:

```
<asp:GridView>
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="StudName" DataField="Name" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="StudAddress" DataField="Address" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="StudPhNo" DataField="PhNo" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Server Side Code:

```
Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //removes all columns ffrom grid.
    for(int i=0;i<gridview1.Columns.Count;i++)
        gridview1.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
}



Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridview1.DataSource = StudList;
    //corrected name of grid
    gridview1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Are you trying to remove all columns (make the GridView invisible)?

Comment: Yes, but i am inrested to know why thi scode segment display my grid in asp.net 2.0 and does not display in asp.net 4.0

Comment: I can test with both, I will give it a try today.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample shows you running an unnecessary `for` loop to remove column 0. I would remove this loop if you only intend to remove the first column. Using `RemoveAt(0)` will always reference your first column, and once you've removed `Columns[0]` your next column along becomes `Columns[0]`, this will be stripping your columns away.

Additionally, you're specifying a datasource for your **gridview1** `GridView`, and then attemping to `DataBind()` a seperate `GridView`, **gridview**.

If you want to *hide* a column I'd suggest you do this:

```
gridview1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

where 0 is your column index.